# Writing a volume shadow service writer in C#

Tags: c#, volume-shadow-service

Has anyone done this? I have found the [AlphaVSS](http://alphavss.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex, but is stops short of providing a way to implement a writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the AlphaVSS page mentions, the VSS APIs are not a real COM API (and therefore are not useable via COM interop). They are just C++ APIs that sort of look like COM. So it's of little use to pure managed code. You need some kind of C++ wrapper or shim regardless what you want to do.